# SQLite how to store translations

Tags: database-design, performance, sqlite

Im looking for advise because my experience is not really good in SQLite.

My table look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Route (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  localizedName blob NOT NULL
);
```

Im storing the localized name of the route as a binary blob in the **localizedName** property(it can hold multiple strings like English, French etc...). then to retrieve it I use a special SQL function

```
SELECT * FROM Route WHERE tkLocalizedString('en', localizedName) LIKE ?1;
```

> **tkLocalizedString** is a function written in C programming language and is added to SQLite at runtime and it accept 2 parameters, the first is the language code (ISO 639-2), the second is the localized string blob
>
> **localizedName** is a binary string table. The key is the language id and the value is the string.

**Is this a good practice? Is there a better approach?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a separate table to hold translation because maintaining the custom functions and translation blob is a non necessary complexity and is not a portable solution.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Route (
  id integer PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name text NOT NULL,
  nameLocalizationId INTEGER REFERENCES Localization(id)
);
```

The localization table have 3 columns:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Localization (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    language TEXT NOT NULL,
    text TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

- **id** is the translations id (its possible to have multiple rows with same id),
- **language** is the *BCP 47* language tag,
- **text** is the localized string.